# How to make screen under a menu inactive (greyed out) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have a bottom navigation bar. Clicking one of the items brings a menu up from the the navigation bar. Simultaneously I'd like the the background screen to become  inactive. Similar to the behaviour of the modal bottom sheet.

Comment: how about make your menu higher, with the upper part opacity = 0?

Comment: never thought of that! Would the opacity render what's underneath it inactive?

Comment: I believe it depends on how you manage your state.  are you using 'stack' to show your menu?

Comment: sorry for the late response, no not using stacks